# Assistance with temperature comparisons assignment in C#

Tags: c#

I'm kinda new to C#, and I'm currently doing an assignment which is having me do three things:

1) Write a program named TemperaturesComparison that allows a user to input five daily Fahrenheit temperatures that must range from −30 to 130.

2) Display the temperatures in the order they were entered, and then display the average of the temperatures.

**3) If a temperature is out of range, require the user to reenter it. If no temperature is lower than any previous one, display a message Getting warmer. If every temperature is lower than the previous one, display a message Getting cooler. If the temperatures are not entered in either ascending or descending order, display a message It’s a mixed bag.**

The first two I've basically already got, but I'm not 100% sure how to address the third one in the most convenient way. Any advice on how to best handle this one would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a sample of the code I've written so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

class TemperaturesComparison {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       string userInput;
       // Set Array Range
       const int ARRAY_RANGE = 5;
       const double AVG_RANGE = 5.0;
       int[] dblArray = new int[ARRAY_RANGE];
       int total = 0;
       double average = 0; 

       WriteLine("This application calculates the average temperature of a provided dataset.\n");

       for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_RANGE; ++i) {
           do { 
               Write("\nPlease provide temperature {0}: ", i + 1);
               userInput = ReadLine();
           } while (!int.TryParse(userInput, out dblArray[i]));
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_RANGE; ++i) {
           total += dblArray[i];
       }

       foreach(var numListHolding in dblArray)
                    Write(numListHolding.ToString() + " ");

       average = total / AVG_RANGE; 
       Write("\nAverage: {0}", average);   
       ReadKey();  
   }
}
```

Comment: For the ascending/descending pattern, you could probably use [`.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) with [`.Skip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). You can use `arrayName.Skip(1)` to obtain the array starting at index 1. Then you can use `arrayName.Zip(...)` to combine the two of them and return a boolean result of the comparison of aTemp > bTemp. If all entries are true, it's getting colder. False, hotter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're making a few common beginner mistakes. First, arrays are better for collections that have a fixed size and never change, like the months of a year. If you want to have a changing number of entries, use something like a list:

```
var temperatures = new List<float>();
```

Second, integers are a poor type for real-world measurements like temperature. Prefer a floating-point type like `float` or `double`.

Next, variable names should tell you what the variables contain; names like `userInput` don't tell us that.

Next, your code doesn't “allow” a user to input five temperatures, it requires them to enter exactly five and will throw exceptions if they don't. Design your loops to work with any number of inputs:

```
while (true)
{
    var nextTemperature = GetTemperatureFromSomewhere();
    if (nextTemperature == null)
        break;

    if (nextTemperature is valid)
        temperatures.Add(nextTemperature);
}
```

Look at the code above. If `nextTemperature` is not null but out of range you don't want to add it to `temperatures`.

When you have that working you want to store a `maximumTemperature` and compare it to each `nextTemperature`. If every `nextTemperature` exceeds `maximumTemperature` then your temperatures are getting warmer.